# Data analysis tool like MS excel 

Tags: excel, graph, data-analysis

I have a large number of data that needs to be compared,
We are using Microsoft EXCEL, it costs, and it is slow, besides the graph that it generates is also not up to the mark.
Now, is their any other tool, that is free, and has good graph's facility.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need good data analysis toolkit, you can spend some time and try [R](http://www.r-project.org) --- free software statistics/data analysis toolkit. It has pretty good graphic capabilities, especially via [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/)  package for static graphics and [ggobi](http://www.ggobi.org/) for dynamic data exploration.

Data import/export pretty easy too --- R can import csv/tsv, or Excel data via ODBC and so on.

- [Pretty good introduction in exploration data analysis with R and ggplot](http://had.co.nz/thesis/practical-tools-hadley-wickham.pdf)
- [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)
- [Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.pdf)

It takes some time to learn, but after that you are not limited with tool capabilities: R can handle plenty of analysis tasks: from simple data crunching, pivoting. aggregation tasks to advanced statistics/machine learning methods: clustering/classification/ regression etc.

If you more more interested in data transformation with simple calculations, you can use some kind of Extract-Transform-Load toolkit, such as [Talend Open Studio](http://www.talend.com/products-data-integration/talend-open-studio.php).

Comment: Is that R a descendant of the APL langage that I loved in the 80s ?

Comment: maybe not direct :)
R is a descendant of S language

Answer (score 1):

If you already have MS Office Suite, you probably have MS Access already installed. It does a better job of processing heaps of data, and is a bit more versatile in graphing/charting/displaying data. There may be a bit of a learning curve if you've never used it before.

As for free: I like working with [Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/), which is free-ish under certain circumstances. At very least its charts are marginally nicer to look at than Excel 2003.

It's going to be difficult to find a free, fast, powerful alternative that generates classy charts though, unless you're willing to code something yourself in, say a web interface.

Comment: I almost used JS Charts for a project at work when I couldn't get Excel to cooperate. Ended up finding a solution in Excel, but putting together the JS Charts version took about 2 hours tops for something that had been bothering me for days in Excel.

Comment: Yeah, if long term viability isn't a concern one could accomplish a lot via web browsers. At minimum, there're heaps of tools and tutorials for presenting web data, not to mention jQuery and all the other eye candy libraries. 

Me? With my luck I just know I'm gonna come across code from these little one-shot projects again one day, probably baked into some unwieldy homebrew system and twisted to fit some heinous "enterprise" solution.